# How to handle cursor from a stored procedure in DB2 9.7

Tags: stored-procedures, cursor, db2

I looked around in manuals on how to use cursors in DB2. However I am still unsure how to implement the following screnario:

caller: a client SQL calls the stored procedure and loops through the values in cursor

stored procedure: the stored procedure being called selects rows from a specific column

Is the cursor declared in the caller or the stored procedure? Sometimes I see the cursor being declared in the caller script, other times the cursor is declared in the stored procedure making the row select. Either way is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure will define the cursor and return it to the calling application.

There are 2 requirements to do this:

1. When you create the procedure you specify `RESULT SETS n` to tell DB2 that the procedure will return result sets to the client application.
2. When you declare the cursor in the stored procedure, you must specify the `WITH RETURN` option to indicate that this cursor will be passed back to the calling application.
3. `OPEN` the cursor within the stored procedure.

If you read the documentation for the [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008329.html) statement, there is an example at the bottom of the page that shows this.